# How to play Video after some interval of time, when app is exit in Android

Tags: android, video

I want to play my video after some interval of time, say 5 minutes. I'll use Broadcast Receiver for this and also try Services but receive no results.

Please help me in this, I do lots of RN D for this, but not getting right answer.

My Problem: I set some time, say 5 minutes and I exit from my app. When I exit from the app, after 5 minutes my video starts playing in front in Android. 
The Video only play when my phone is in IDLE state, when user is not working on his phone, then my video will play.

How can I do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add broadcast receiver in your app and notify your app after 5 mins so that your app starts after 5 mins and plays the video.

Comment: @Khush Actually i didn't understand your question, Anyway i hope you are using services to play video in 5 minutes time interval correct me if am wrong. Are you using Aync task to do the same in Service? or any timers ?

Comment: i use broadcast receiver but it doesn't work

Comment: can u give me some links or code which can help me

Comment: now i am playing song becoz i dont  know how to show video

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.savebtn:

        String sURL = video_url.getText().toString();
        if (sURL.matches("")) {
            video_url.requestFocus();
            video_url.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            return;
        }

        String sid = deviceid_et.getText().toString();
        if (sid.matches("")) {
            deviceid_et.requestFocus();
            deviceid_et.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            return;
        }

        String stout = timeout_et.getText().toString();
        if (stout.matches("")) {
            timeout_et.requestFocus();
            timeout_et.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            return;
        }

        String supdate = update_et.getText().toString();
        if (supdate.matches("")) {
            update_et.requestFocus();
            update_et.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            return;
        }

         startAlert(); 

      //    Intent intent = new Intent(context,VideoPlayerActivity.class);
      //    startActivity(intent);
          overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);                 
          break;

   case R.id.cancelbtn:
        finish();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

 public void startAlert() {  
        EditText timeout_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeout_et);  
        int i = Integer.parseInt(timeout_et.getText().toString());  
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);  
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  
                                      this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);  
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);  
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()  
                                      + ((i * 1000)*60), pendingIntent);  
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " minutes",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
```

}

Broadcast Receiver class

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

 MediaPlayer mp;  

    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

        mp=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sun   );  
        mp.start();  
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

    /*   System.out.println("jjjjjjjjjjjj");
         Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
         scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);      */
    }  
}
```

Comment: In Broadcast Receiver class, it play song correctly. But if i Intent my VideoPlayerActivity...it doesnt work. As there is no need of any view for songs, but for videos it need some view.